# Is it safe to set java.io.tmpdir to <INSTANCE>/tmp in JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We have multiple instances of JBoss 5.1.0 running on the same physical server, using multiple instances of the same VM:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/server/instance1
<JBOSS_HOME>/server/instance2
```

with the appropriate configuration to avoid port clashes etc.

For each instance there is the tmp folder:

```
<JBOSS_HOME>/server/instance1/tmp
<JBOSS_HOME>/server/instance2/tmp
```

To keep things separate, is it ok to set the `java.io.tmpdir` variable to `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/<INSTANCE>/tmp`?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, but JBoss might be assuming it has full control over the contents of that directory. It might be a good idea to create a directory under `<INSTANCE>/tmp`, and set `java.io.tmpdir` to that, it would likely reduce the risk of any collisions.